# Вставка html кода с помощью css

Tags: html, css

Есть простой кусок кода:

```
<h1>Каталог товаров</h1>.
```

Перед ним нужно вставить ссылку:

```
<a href="мойсайт.ру">Главная</a>
```

Проблема в том, что это нужно сделать только с помощью `css`. При использовании `:before` отображается просто текст, а не `html` тэг. Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Увы, но так вы не сделаете. Без javascript тут не обойтись...

Comment: Не делать такого с помощью css. Может меня поправят, но нельзя в `content` вставить *html*-код. По крайней мере нельзя было раньше. Можно было *css* стили в контент добавлять, и то не во всех браузерах работало это.

Comment: Проблема в том, что доступа до html кода нет. Если можно сделать с помощью JS - как это сделать?

Comment: Почитайте [справку](http://htmlbook.ru/css/content) о том, как работает свойство "content" и поймете, что хотите невозможного

Comment: Если хотите вывести html код с помощью javascript, то в качестве самого простого способа используйте `document.write('<a href="мойсайт.ру">Главная</a>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На `css` нет такой возможности. Используя `js` можно примерно таким способом:

```js
var section = document.querySelector("div.section"),
    link = document.createElement("a"), // создаём <a></a>
    linkText = document.createTextNode("Главаня"); // добавляем анкор "Главаня"
    link.appendChild(linkText); // <a>Главаня</a>
    link.href = "мойсайт.ру"; // <a href="мойсайт.ру">Главаня</a>

 section.insertBefore(link, section.firstChild); // Добавляем всё это дело в начало блока .section
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <h1>Каталог товаров</h1>
</div>
```

используя `jquery` достаточно будет:

```
$( '<a href="мойсайт.ру">Главаня</a>' ).insertBefore( "h1" );
```